# Helptext property of Button

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, morph-x

In my form, i updated lables and helptext of some buttons in form's init method, forms label are updated, but helptext is still not updating, when i click that button, it shows updated helptext.

i tried element.lock/unlock but no luck.

below is my code in init:

```
if (element.args().menuItemName() == menuitemDisplayStr(PhcPurchRFQCaseTableForNew) || PhcpurchRFQCaseTableRec.PhcIsInvitationToBid == NoYes::Yes
    || element.args().menuItemName() == menuitemDisplayStr(PhcPurchRFQCaseTableListPageAction))
{
    purchRFQCaseTableForm.parmPhcIsInvitationToBid(NoYes::Yes);
    _PhcIsInvitationToBid = NoYes::Yes;
    element.PhcUpdateDesignLabels(); // this is to update labels
}
```

and below is the method:

```
public void PhcUpdateDesignLabels()
{
    this.lockWindowUpdate(true);

    HeaderGeneral.caption("@PHC204");
    HeaderLinesGrid.caption("@PHC205");
    NewCommandButton.text("@PHC173");
    NewCommandButton.helpText("@PHC157");
    PurchRFQConfigReply1.text("@PHC196");
    PurchRFQConfigReply1.helpText("@PHC175");
    RFQJournalMenuItemButton.text("@PHC195");
    RFQJournalMenuItemButton.helpText("@PHC177");
    RFQInfo.caption("@PHC206");
    QouteActionPaneTab.caption("@PHC180");
    PurchRFQTable_RFQId.label("@PHC173");
    RFQInfo_PhcQuotationType.label("@PHC250");
    CopyFromMenuItemButton.helpText("@PHC262");
    SendMenuItemButton.helpText("@PHC263");
    EnterReplyMenuItemButton.helpText("@PHC264");
    CompareRepliesMenuItemButton.helpText("@PHC251");

    this.lockWindowUpdate(false);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried commenting the `lockWindowUpdate` out?

Comment: @alphaprolix, are you sure your button is in focus when the HelpText expected by you is not being displayed?

Comment: Jan, yes i tried commenting it, still not showing latest helptext
10p, i am mouse overing on my buttons, they get highlighted and helptext appears, but default helptext.
You guys can try on your environment, form's name is PurchRFQCaseTable.